# Procurar objetos em runtime

Tags: c#

Tenho uma aplicação que irá fazer downloads simultâneos de diferentes fontes de dados. Nela tenho um `DataGridView` que irá receber o `result` de um select e a partir da quantidade de linhas que vierem desse `result` terei a mesma quantidade de `TabPages`. Cada `TabPage` vai ter um `Textbox` para gravar o andamento dos downloads. Os downloads são feitos em períodos, que também são variáveis, depende da configuração de download. Dito isso, tenho a seguinte situação... Como toda vez que rodo a consulta, eu monto novos objetos e até mesmo crio o `Timer` e o `BackgroundWorker` para executar todas as ações.

Para evitar criar muitas abas, eu estou percorrendo o `TabControl` em um foreach e utilizando o `TabPage.Dispose()` para liberar os recursos da aplicação. Só que não encontrei um meio de fazer o mesmo com o `Timer` e o `BackgroundWorker`. Como eu poderia encontrar os dois para "matar" eles em tempo de execução?

> Update: Código de criação dos objetos

```
    private void createLogColTab(int pCodigoCol,
                                    string pTipoCol)
    {
        TabPage tbpNew = new TabPage();
        tbpNew.Tag = pCodigoCol.ToString();
        tbpNew.Name = "tbpLogCol" + clsGeneric.TruncateLongString(pCodigoCol.ToString(), 3, "R", "0");
        tbpNew.Text = pTipoCol;
        tbpNew.Height = panel1.Height;
        tbpNew.Width = panel1.Width;

        TextBox txtResult = new TextBox();
        txtResult.Name = "txtLogCol" + clsGeneric.TruncateLongString(pCodigoCol.ToString(), 3, "R", "0");
        txtResult.Multiline = true;
        txtResult.Height = tbpNew.Height;
        txtResult.Width = tbpNew.Width;
        txtResult.Text = tbpNew.Name;
        txtResult.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top);
        txtResult.Tag = pCodigoCol.ToString();

        Timer tmrNew = new Timer();
        tmrNew.Tag = pCodigoCol.ToString();

        BackgroundWorker bgwNew = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgwNew.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bgwNew.DoWork += bgwMain_DoWork;
        bgwNew.ProgressChanged += bgwMain_ProgressChanged;
        bgwNew.RunWorkerCompleted += bgwMain_RunWorkerCompleted;

        tbcLogColeta.TabPages.Add(tbpNew);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Timer tem um evento `Elapsed` ([Timer.Elapsed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx)) em que você pode verificar (com uma variável global) se esse timer ainda precisa ser executado. Se não precisar, você desabilita ele.

No caso do BackgroundWorker, ele tem a propriedade `WorkerSupportsCancellation`:

```
bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
```

Onde você pode cancelar a execução:

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    for (int i = 1; (i <= 10); i++)
    {
        if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            worker.ReportProgress((i * 10));
        }
    }
}
```

Nos links abaixo tem exemplos desse uso:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx#Anchor_1

Mas, em ambos os casos, o worker está declarado global. Você conseguiria fazer isso no teu caso? Declarar uma lista (ou um dicionário) de workers globalmente?

---

**EDIT**

Conforme conversamos sobre o dicionário global:

```
// Dicionários:
private Dictionary<string, Timer> _allTimers = new Dictionary<string, Timer>();
private Dictionary<string, BackgroundWorker> _allWorkers = new Dictionary<string, BackgroundWorker>();

private void createLogColTab(int pCodigoCol,
                                string pTipoCol)
{
    TabPage tbpNew = new TabPage();
    tbpNew.Tag = pCodigoCol.ToString();
    tbpNew.Name = "tbpLogCol" + clsGeneric.TruncateLongString(pCodigoCol.ToString(), 3, "R", "0");
    tbpNew.Text = pTipoCol;
    tbpNew.Height = panel1.Height;
    tbpNew.Width = panel1.Width;

    TextBox txtResult = new TextBox();
    txtResult.Name = "txtLogCol" + clsGeneric.TruncateLongString(pCodigoCol.ToString(), 3, "R", "0");
    txtResult.Multiline = true;
    txtResult.Height = tbpNew.Height;
    txtResult.Width = tbpNew.Width;
    txtResult.Text = tbpNew.Name;
    txtResult.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top);
    txtResult.Tag = pCodigoCol.ToString();

    Timer tmrNew = new Timer();
    tmrNew.Tag = pCodigoCol.ToString();

    // Adicionar ao dicionário:
    _allTimers.Add(pCodigoCol.ToString(), tmrNew);

    BackgroundWorker bgwNew = new BackgroundWorker();
    bgwNew.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bgwNew.DoWork += bgwMain_DoWork;
    bgwNew.ProgressChanged += bgwMain_ProgressChanged;
    bgwNew.RunWorkerCompleted += bgwMain_RunWorkerCompleted;

    // Adicionar ao dicionário:
    _allWorkers.Add(pCodigoCol.ToString(), bgwNew);

    tbcLogColeta.TabPages.Add(tbpNew);
}
```

Comment: Então, o problema é que eu crio o `Timer` e o `BackgroundWorker` dinamicamente para cada linha que eu tiver, se retornar 3 linhas do BD, eu terei 3 `Timers` e 3 `BackgroundWorkers`, pois o sistema tem de fazer as 3 operações simultâneamente. Se você ver o código que acabei de incluir, eu não consigo vincular o `Timer` ou o `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: Você não consegue montar uma chave `string` única para cada linha e criar um `Dictionary` global com essa string como chave e o `Timer`/`BackgroundWorker` como valor?

Comment: Incluí um exemplo na resposta.

Comment: A sua solução é perfeita Rick, vou implementar ela. Mas só por curiosidade, o TabPage tem uma propriedade chamada "Container", tem algum meio de utilizar essa propriedade para incluir o Timer e o BackgroundWorker?

Comment: Cara, nunca usei esse Container do TabPage. Olhando na documentação eu vi que o Timer herda de IComponent e o Container tem uma lista de Components (que são IComponent). Mas não sei se isso funcionaria e nem como. Só testando para descobrir...  :P